# How to make control move from inner loop to outer loop if a transaction fails

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have nested while loops with a transaction in the inner loop, e.g.:

```
WHILE -- A
BEGIN
    WHILE -- B
    BEGIN
        -- tx here
    END
END
```

I need to shift control from the inner loop (B) to the outer loop (A) if the transaction fails.

Comment: @evilone it took me a moment but I think my answer captures what Elly was asking.

Comment: @Aaron +1 for understanding question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously pseudo but the important part is the `BREAK`; inside `CATCH`. How it behaves, though, will depend on the error level / severity of the actual failure.

```
WHILE ...
BEGIN
    WHILE ...
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            -- attempt tx here
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            BREAK; -- this will bring you back to outer while
        END CATCH
    END
END
```

P.S. the absolute bible on error handling was written by Erland Sommarskog, you should definitely put it in your bookmarks:

http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html

Comment: +1: I ***always*** forget that T-SQL has BREAK and CONTINUE.  Dang!